# Customizing functions across a Python class hierarchy

Tags: python, class, metaclass

I have a hierarchy of classes whose definitions I can't edit directly. I would like to wrap each class in the hierarchy such that some functions are customized.

To give a much simplified example, let's say we have a hierarchy of animals:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def sound(self):
        pass

class Cat(Animal):
    def sound(self):
        return "Meow"

class Dog(Animal):
    def sound(self):
        return "Woof"

class Cow(Animal):
    def sound(self):
        return "Moo"
```

Now, if I want to modify the `sound` method of one of the animals, I could just inherit the class:

```py
class LoudDog(Dog):
    def sound(self):
        return super().sound().upper()
```

But ideally I should be able to make a wrapper that allows me to make a loud version of any `Animal` class, something like this:

```py
LoudDog = Loud(Dog)
LoudCat = Loud(Cat)
LoutCow = Loud(Cow)
```

What would be the best / most pythonic way to achieve this? The syntax doesn't have to be exactly as above. I was thinking metaclasses might be useful here, but I don't have a lot of experience with those and I'll be happy with other solutions too.

Comment: You could use it as a mix-in - `class LoudDog(Loud, Dog): pass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approch that will create a new class based on the given one, and tune its "sound" method

```py
from copy import deepcopy

def loud(animal_class):
    loud_class = deepcopy(animal_class) # to avoid modifying the real class
    old_sound = animal_class.sound # to avoid recursion
    loud_class.sound = lambda self: old_sound(self).upper()
    return loud_class

LoudCow = loud(Cow)
LoudCow().sound() # prints "MOO'
```

You can also try, as suggested, a mix-in:

```py
class Loud():
  def __init__(self):
    old_sound = self.sound
    self.sound = lambda: old_sound.upper()

class LoudDog(Dog, Loud): pass
LoudDog().sound() # prints "WOOF"
```

Comment: In the mix-in solution, do I have to replace functions like that, or can I somehow use `super`?

Comment: Since the `Loud` class has no "super", you cannot. It is kind of a hack, since it relies on the `self` object already having a `sound` method, if you try to use it without an `Animal` it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping things simple, if you don't need the extra classes, just the different behavior, your callable could just strap callables that will work as bound methods to the instances:

```py
def bound(instance: Animal):
    original_sound = instance.sound
    def loud(*args):
        new = original_sound()
        return new.upper()
    instance.sound = loud
    # not needed, but can be used to curry various such calls:
    return instance
```

If you actually need the classes, you can simply use multiple inheritance:

```py
class Loud:
    def sound(self):
         original = super.sound()
         return original.upper()

class LoudCat(Loud, Cat):
   pass
```

In this case, on the new class, Python will first locate the "sound" method in the Loud class, and `super()` will pick the next class on the `__mro__` (method resolution order) - which will be the other base class.

Answer (score 0):

Since I mentioned in my post that you might be able to solve this with metaclasses, here's a solution using those. After the class definitions in my original post, you can do the following:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta

class Loud(ABCMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):
        instance = super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
        if not issubclass(instance, Animal):
            raise AttributeError("The base class must derive from Animal.")

        def sound(self):
            return super(instance, self).sound().upper()

        instance.sound = sound
        
        return instance

class LoudCat(Cat, metaclass=Loud):
    pass

class LoudDog(Dog, metaclass=Loud):
    pass

class LoudCow(Cow, metaclass=Loud):
    pass
```

Now we get:

```py
>>> LoudCat().sound()
MEOW
>>> LoudDog().sound()
WOOF
>>> LoudCow().sound()
MOO
```